# Powershell switch null or empty

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I need to write a switch with 2 possibilities. Either $JobHostEndpoint variable exist with value or it doesn't(or have a null value).

```
Param ([string[]]$BrandID,$ReportName,$JobHostEndpoint)

$ReportPath = "C:\Nehjk\Web\NScheduler\NvbhjJobHost.exe"

switch ( $JobHostEndpoint ){    
    default { $Args = "JobIssueReport BrandID=$BRANDID ReportName=$ReportName" }
    !$null { $Args = "JobIssueReport BrandID=$BRANDID ReportName=$ReportName JobHostEndpoint=$JobHostEndpoint" }
}
echo "Args is $Args"
```

Problem that this switch construct doesn't assign anything to $Args variable:

```
PS C:> echo "Args is $Args"
Args is
```

What is the problem with my switch construction?

Comment: `if ($JobHostEndpoint) { Write-Host "No Value" } else { Write-Host "Has Value" }`

Comment: @gvee Wouldn't it be the other way around? `If ($variable) {Write-Output "Has Value"} else {Write-Output "No Value"}`

Comment: @I.TDelinquent you are quite right - doy!

Comment: Automatic variable `$args` is definitely to be avoided as a custom variable, but your code as written does not explain your symptom. If you tried to access your custom `$args` from another function, however, you would _not_ see your custom value. Please update your question to clarify the scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$args is a special variable

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/powershell_special_variables.htm

Try settings using an other variable name like $args1